# The $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^\infty \sin(r)r\,dr}{te^t}$ doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

We have that $\int_0^\infty \sin(r)r \, dr=\pm \infty$ (doesn't exist) so my guess is that

$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^\infty \sin(r)r\,dr}{te^t}=\pm \infty$ even though the exponential grows faster.

We can also write this as $\lim_{t\to \infty}\lim_{R\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^R \sin(r)r\,dr}{te^t}$.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean for the integral to have bounds which depend on $t$?

Comment: no, I meant what I wrote. This is not a textbook question.

Comment: Perhaps they meant $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^t\sin(r)~r~dr}{t~e^t}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $I=\int_0^{\infty}r\sin r\,dr$ doesn't exist, it follows that there is no real number $t$ for which $I/(te^t)$ exists, and a fortiori $\lim_{t\to\infty}(I/(te^t))$ can't possibly exist.

Comment: Prettier and more concise,but basically the same answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator is a DEFINITE integral,whicb is a number. So technically,only the denominator is a function of t. However,clearly the numerator goes to infinity,so it's not a limit that exists so by that reasoning alone, the limit doesn't exist. In that sense,the problem is really a trick question. You have to recognize that the numerator doesn't exist,which means the limit cannot exist! I made that mistake in my initial attempt to solve the problem-I attempted to use L'Hopital's rule-in essence, I treated the numerator as **an indefinite integral** Which is course,completely wrong. Which is why it really is critical to be absolutely clear what terms are present! Carelessness can cost!